# How to convert this callback based node.js code, to rxjs?

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I am trying to use node.js libraries that are based on callbacks, using rxjs, to see if its possible to do it in simple way.
Can someone write this code using rxjs? I mean remove the callbacks and use rxjs, not another library like "rxjs/ajax".

```js
const options = new URL("http://localhost:8080/");
http.request(options, (response) => {
  let body = "";
  response.on("data", (chunk) => (body += chunk));
  response.on("end", () => {
    console.log(body);
  });
}).end();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea to write self-owned HTTP request library based on an Observable pattern?

In a common way you can do it in the example below:

```
// listening and sent request to subject
app.get('/', (req, res) => subject.next([req, res]));
...
// operation with payload and response
subject.subscribe(([req, res]) => {
   res.send('Hello World!');
 });
```

Comment: the idea is how to use node.js from reactive progrmaming, and convert the callbacks to reactive code. for example rxjs has a method fromNodeCallback, but seems to me that its not trivial to use rxjs from node.js 's callback based apis.